# Save command line history only if exit code is 0

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

I looked in `~/.bash_history` and I can see all the commands I have executed, even those with typos. Is there a way to save only the commands that have succeeded (i.e. exit code 0)?

Note: I am using bash and zsh.

Comment: Using bash the `$?` variable holds the exit status of the command executed.

Answer (score 1):

Save this in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
good_history(){ 
  exit_status=$?
  if ((!exit_status)); then 
     history 1 >> history.txt
  fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="good_history"
```

After that source `~/.bashrc` run `source ~/.bashrc`

- The above construct is function definition, `function_name() { command_goes_here; }`
- Only commands that exited with `0` is save in the file `history.txt`
- As far as the shell is concern the exit status `0` is a success and the rest are a failure.
- The builtin variable  `$?` holds the last exit status of the last command executed, interactive or not.
- In math context using bash `0` is a failure and `1` is a success when using the `(( ))` so we negate using bang `!` character, see `help test`
- The `>>` is to append to wherever that thing is pointing to, in this case to a file.
- See the section in the bash manual about the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable try running in your shell session `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*PROMPT_COMMAND' man bash`
- You may or may not need the `export` but I'm not sure what setup you have in your `shellrc` files so It is there.
- Wait for someone who is using `zsh`